# linear restriction on a particular covariance matrix

Tags: hypothesis-testing, covariance

Suppose I have this covariance matrix of regression coefficient for $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$

\begin{pmatrix}
&5 &-3\\
&-3& 0.5\\
\end{pmatrix}

And I'm going to test 
$\begin{cases}
H_0:\beta_1+\beta_2=1\\
H_1:\beta_1+\beta_2\neq 1
\end{cases}$

If I am going to test with t-ratio I need to compute $se(\hat{\beta_1}-\hat{\beta_2}-1)$ so the square root of the variance:

$VAR(\hat{\beta_1}-\hat{\beta_2}-1)=VAR(\hat{\beta_1})+VAR(\hat{\beta_2})+2cov(VAR(\hat{\beta_1}),VAR(\hat{\beta_1}))=5+0.5-2*3<0$

This is an error depending on the covariance matrix which is not positive definite (in fact real part of the eigenvalues are not all positive).
AM I right?

Comment: How did you get this covariance matrix?

Comment: On an exercise, but I think that there is obviously an error on the covariance matrix.

Answer (score -1):

covariance matrix is always non-negative definite if your design matrix is full rank. 
Just compute your t-ratio as:
t-value=(β1+β2-1)/sqrt([1 1] * covb * [1 1]')

Comment: 1) Every covariance matrix is positive semi-definite. 2) sqrt([1 1] * covb * [1 1]' is Negative!